# What's common explanation of 'hammer, meet nail'?

Tags: meaning

Would someone explain what exactly that means?

Also is it right that there is comma between 'hammer' and 'meet'?

Source: http://youtu.be/RidsxnnVTR4

Lyrics in print: http://www.lyricstime.com/dr-horrible-s-sing-along-blog-slipping-lyrics.html

Comment: I didn't know it was an idiom.  I've only heard it in *Dr. Horrible's Sing-Along Blog*.  Anyway, I have no idea what it means, but presumably you're introducing hammer to nail, so the comma is appropriate.

Comment: I think that in *Dr. Horrible*, it was being used as a failed witticism.  Like, it was supposed to sound something like "hammer, meet anvil"--the anvil is hardened, so the hammer breaks.  But he's calling himself the *nail*, and nails get pounded down by hammers.  So it makes you giggle a little after you hear it.

Comment: @snailboat, I think you're right, but could you please write this as answer, not comment? so I'd be able to accept it and close the question.

Comment: I'm hesitant, because I have the feeling this might be too localized if it's not an actual idiom.  (Then again, Too Localized is going away...)  As a rule, I don't want to answer a question if I'm going to vote to close, and I haven't decided yet.

Comment: @snailboat, also NAIL sounds like NEIL :) I think it's sarcasm: he says to society that superhero is hammer, but now nail (villian) wins vs hammer. Paradox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call this an established idiom, but it's not uncommon to use two objects which strike each other, such as a hammer and a nail, to create a metaphor. One of the first examples that springs into my mind is from the song *The Bug*, which actually uses two such vehicles in its chorus:

> *Sometimes you're the windshield
>
> Sometimes you're the bug
>
> Sometimes it all comes together baby
>
> Sometimes you're just a fool in love
>
> Sometimes you're the Louisville Slugger
>
> Sometimes you're the ball
>
> Sometimes it all comes together
>
> Sometimes you're gonna lose it all*

One [blogger](http://www.jettct.com/speaking-training/sometimes-youre-the-bug/) alluded to that song lyric in a column about stress. It's a catchy way to express the sentiment.

In short, I be very unlikely to insert the exact phrase "hammer, meet nail" into a conversation, even while talking about someone who was about to get a raw deal. But, particularly in the context of a musical, the phrase doesn't strike me as being off in any way.